# Bootstrap Modal having problem but unable to fix it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

It's opening a new window and the close button is working fine but "Save Changes" button is not submitting the form.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Modal Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#primary0">
<button type=butto class="font-awesome-btn">
    <i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit
</button>


</a> <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="primary0" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"  aria-hidden="true">
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8080/editStatus" method="post">
<div class="modal-dialog" backdrop="static" keyboard="false">
<div class="modal-content">

<!-- Modal Header -->
<div class="modal-header modal-header-primary">
  <button type="button" class="close order-1" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  </button>
  <h4><i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i> Updating Status</h4>
</div>

<!-- Modal body -->
<div class="modal-body">
  <h3>Please write new value for:</br><span class=red><b>Active</b></span></h3>
  <input type="hidden" name="statusId" value="1">
  <input type="text" name="status" value="">
</div>

<!-- Modal footer -->
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type=button class="font-awesome-btn">
  <i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> Save Changes
  </button>
  <button type=button class="font-awesome-btn" data-dismiss="modal">
  <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Close
  </button>
</div>


</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</form>
</div><!-- /.modal -->
                                        
                                        
                                        
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```